# What does this line in python mean?

Tags: python

I came across this line in a Python code and don't know how what it does

```
[np.int32(track) for track in self.tracks]
```

This was the context, the code was a perceptron classifier:

```
def draw_track(self, image):
    """Draw track lines on image."""
    cv2.polylines(image, [np.int32(track) for track in self.tracks], False, (0, 255, 0))
```

Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: That is list comprehension.

Comment: That line creates a new list that is like `self.tracks`, but each element has the type `np.int32`.

Comment: It converts all elements in tracks list into `int32` datatype.

Comment: @techytushar: You know this, but to be clear for the OP: It doesn't change `tracks`, it makes a new `list` with the converted elements, leaving `tracks` unmodified (unless it's an iterator, in which case it's exhausted/emptied in the process of building the new `list`).

Answer (score 1):

It is a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). It is the equivalent of :

```
lst = []
for track in self.tracks:
    lst.append(np.int32(track))
```